# How to get active Chrome tab in Python?

Tags: python, google-chrome, windows-7

I would like to be able to get the currently active URL in Chrome / Chromium from a Python script running on the same machine (Windows 7, Python 3.x) . For some reason this seems impossible at the limits of my ability to search out. Does anyone know a way to do so?

Other features which would be ideal for a solution but aren't necessary:

- Seeing if the Chrome window is actually the active task via window manager or other such system.
- Working for multiple browsers - especially Firefox, Chrome, and Internet Explorer
- Able to retrieve other data about the page - Title attribute, most notably.
- Working across multiple operating systems. It'd be nice to not have to rewrite or restart this for Linux and OSX.

I've looked through options before asking:

- Google's (deprecated?) Python API doesn't seem to cover accessing the Chromium underpinnings of Chrome on the same system.
- Selenium seems to be more for remote control and automated testing where user is unlikely to ever see a window (plus isn't pure python?)
- Pythonic core web module is only able - evidently - to open web pages in a browser in an orderly fashion, passing responsibility off to the OS.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: have you tried the webbrowser module?

Comment: _Pythonic core web module is only able - evidently - to open web pages in a browser in an orderly fashion, passing responsibility off to the OS._ ...

[I read the docs. Did you?](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html#browser-controller-objects)